# Работа с несколькими NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Народ, привет!

Приложение может генерить и запускать более одного Таймера. Я попробовал назначать имя каждому таймеру:

```
    NSTimer *appTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(appTimerOn:)
                                           userInfo:timerArray.timerName
                                            repeats:YES];
```

Но вот вопрос: А как мне вызвать конкретный таймер по имени в другой функции (например, кнопка выключения конкретного таймера)?

Или может быть другой способ работы сразу с несколькими таймерами есть?

PS: Вариант с сохранением стронговой переменной - плохой, таймеров может быть много.

Comment: с сохранением переменной это единственный способ. вопрос в деталях. если много кладите их в массив. можно сделать сабкласс/категорию и задать им какие то кастомные имена

Comment: Ага, я так и думал :( Но надеялся, что есть какой-нибуть элегантный способ. Спасибо!

Comment: Просто мне тогда не понятно, зачем userInfo, что он делает?

Comment: в userInfo можно сложить любой объект, который вам может понадобиться, когда таймер выполняет заданный для него @selector. например если несколько таймеров выполняют один и тот же селектор, но вам надо знать который из таймеров выстрелил. или если например вам надо по таймеру совершить действие над конкретным объектом, вы можете его положить в userInfo тогда не надо будет рыть через все приложение, чтоб найти необходимый объект.